# How to add all extra modules of OpenCV-contrib to OpenCV library?

Tags: opencv, cmake, tracking, opencv-contrib

I have built OpenCV with extra modules based on [these instractions](https://cv-tricks.com/how-to/installation-of-opencv-4-1-0-in-windows-10-from-source/) by providing the path:
`C:/opencv/opencv-4.2.0/opencv_contrib-4.2.0/modules`
in **OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH** in **CMake GUI**.

However, when I want to use **MultiTracker** based on [this page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d07/tutorial_multitracker.html) I face this error:

> Cannot open include file: 'samples_utility.hpp': No such file or directory

This error comes from this line:

```c
#include "samples_utility.hpp"
```

I know `samples_utility.hpp` is a file in `opencv_contrib-4.2.0\modules\tracking`, but why is it not found in the built libraries? Do I have to add it from **CMake** or should I build OpenCV from scratch?

Comment: It's [an example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/tracking/samples/samples_utility.hpp), not a part of the library.

Comment: So how should I add it to OpenCV? Should I add it to each project that I want to use?

Comment: If you need the single function it provides, then sure, you can add a copy of the file to your project.